# Linux Driver - RTC PCF85063A - Wakeup Problem

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree, imx6

I'm working in a kernel patch for my imx6ull's embedded Linux image. I'm using a PCF85063A in I2C1, but its wakeup interrupt doesn't work. INT pin is connected to SODIMM 106 and I can't figure out the reason why it's not working.

At boot I get:

```
[    8.487168] rtc-pcf85063 0-0051: registered as rtc0 
[    8.502610] rtc-pcf85063 0-0051: setting system clock to 2023-07-07T16:28:49 UTC (1688747329)
[  146.689736] [<1c6ab285>] irq_default_primary_handler threaded [<b6666757>] pcf85063_rtc_handle_irq
```

If I try to change /sys/power/state, I get:

```
[  266.251231] PM: suspend entry (deep)  
[  266.312442] Filesystems sync: 0.054 seconds
[  266.324553] Freezing user space processes
[  266.339858] Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.010 seconds)
[  266.348429] OOM killer disabled.
[  266.351779] Freezing remaining freezable tasks
[  266.361847] Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 0.005 seconds)
[  266.369741] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  266.494859] PM: suspend devices took 0.110 seconds
[  266.534029] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[  266.820497] PM: resume devices took 0.260 seconds
[  266.840124] OOM killer enabled.
[  266.843347] Restarting tasks ... done.
[  266.884987] random: crng reseeded on system resumption
[  266.912850] PM: suspend exit
-sh: echo: write error: Device or resource busy
```

Using rtcwake (rtcwake -u -s 60 -m mem), I get:

```
[  202.338932] PM: suspend entry (deep)                                         
[  202.376789] Filesystems sync: 0.032 seconds                                  
[  202.393022] systemd-journald[121]: Data hash table of /run/log/journal/1e231.
[  202.416581] Freezing user space processes                                    
[  202.447739] Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.026 seconds)  
[  202.457459] OOM killer disabled.                                             
[  202.460937] Freezing remaining freezable tasks                               
[  202.471934] Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 0.006 seco)
[  202.479707] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)  
[  202.605185] PM: suspend devices took 0.110 seconds                           
[  202.643749] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...                                      
[  202.931423] PM: resume devices took 0.260 seconds                            
[  202.950730] OOM killer enabled.                                              
[  202.953949] Restarting tasks ...                                             
[  202.966793] systemd-journald[121]: /run/log/journal/1e2317323e804be59d671ac5.
[  202.995698] done.                                                            
[  202.998191] random: crng reseeded on system resumption                       
[  203.005129] PM: suspend exit                                                 
rtcwake: write error
```

SODIMM 106 was allocated to touchscreen interrupt, but I've already change it.

Do you have a clue about what I'm doing wrong??

My updates in dt were:

```dts
&i2c1 {
    status = "okay";

    pcf85063: rtc@51 {
      compatible = "nxp,pcf85063a";
      reg = <0x51>;
      pinctrl-names = "default";
      pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_rtc_int>;
      interrupt-parent = <&gpio1>;
      interrupts = <10 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING>; /* SODIMM 106*/
      quartz-load-femtofarads = <12500>;
      clock {
        compatible = "fixed-clock";
        #clock-cells = <0>;
        clock-frequency = <32768>;
      };
    };
  };

&snvs_rtc {
    status = "disabled";
};
```

Comment: I have no idea about the answer to your problem, but FYI in case you weren't aware: It's possible you might get more responses on the Unix SE (unix.stackexchange.com). If you don't get any replies here within a reasonable timeframe, you can consider migrating the question (but note that simple double-/cross-posting is not allowed).

Comment: 1. You seem to be missing the `wakeup-source` property from your device tree. Is it present in an overlay, or somewhere else? 2. Based on dmesg your system wakes up. What wakes it up? Also, do you set rtc alarm before suspending?

Comment: I've already tried to add the wakeup-source, but then I got these errors at boot:
 rtc-pcf85063 0-0051: wake irq already initialized
 rtc rtc0: failed to enable irq wake
In this case I didn't set the alarm, but if I do it doesn't work either. I get the same error:
echo: write error: Device or resource busy

Comment: The `interrupts` and `wakeup-source` properties are mutually exclusive, this is not the issue.

Comment: My guess is that suspending the platform is not working properly.

Comment: In fact the suspending stops working right after the device tree modification to enable the external rtc is applied. If I don't apply the patch that enables it, the suspending and the wakeupalarm work as expected with the internal RTC.